# Ошибка в сортировке

Tags: c++

Условие:

Даны на плоскости точки с координатами (x, y). Переставить точки по возрастанию их расстояния до точки k (заданая, фиксированная точка). Значения х и у находятся во внешнем файле. Результат также необходимо записать на другой внешний файл.

```
FILE *flr,*flw;
double rast(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)  
{ 
     return (pow((x1-x2),2)+pow((y1-y2),2));
};

using namespace std;

int main()

{

int i=0,n=0,k=2;

 float u,v;

if ((flr=fopen("a.txt","r"))==NULL)

{

printf("Error in opening file a.dat \n"); getchar(); exit(0);

}

 while(fscanf(flr, "%i %i", &u, &v) != EOF) {
                   n++;
           }

rewind(flr);
float x[1000],y[1000];

for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++)

{

 fscanf(flr, "%g %g", &u, &v);
    printf("u[%i]=%g v[%i]=%g\n\n",i, u, i, v);
    x[i]=u; y[i]=v;

    };

  int m;
float xk,yk;
xk=x[k];
yk=y[k];
```

float s,t;

```
 for (m=0; m< n ; m++)

{

         for (i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
              if ( (rast(x[i],y[i],xk,yk)) > (rast ( x[m],y[m],xk,yk)) )
              {

                   s=x[i]; t=y[i];
                   cout<<"s="<<s;
                   x[m]=x[i]; y[m]=y[i];
                   x[i]=s; y[i]=t;
              } ;  
          };

  }

    if ((flw=fopen("b.txt","w"))==NULL)//создать файл для записи
    {printf("Error in opening file b.dat \n"); getchar(); exit(0); }

     for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++) 
     { 
         if (i==k){ i++;}
         else 
             fprintf(flw,"u=%g, v=%g\n",x[i],y[i]);

    };
    getchar();
}
```

Сортировка работает неправильно. Помогите поправить код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас неправильно обмениваются элементы, надо так:

```
s=x[i]; t=y[i];
cout<<"s="<<s;
x[i]=x[m]; y[i]=y[m];
x[m]=s; y[m]=t;
```

Comment: @iksuy, а слона-то я и не заметил.. Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

Это потому, что во время сортировки в элементы массивов `x[k]` и `y[k]` постоянно попадают *разные* элементы массивов.

Просто вынесите `x[k]` и `y[k]`  из массивов перед сортировкой в две переменные и сравнивайте с ними.

Comment: @avp, я поправил, но работать правильно программа не стала. ПОчему-то он в s всегда записывает значение первой точки.

Comment: float s[100],t[100];

а ничего что s и t локальные массивы и видны только внутри if? при каждом входе туда они пересоздаются. мне кажется, это вообще не имеет смысла сейчас.

Comment: @iksuy, я поправил. Ничего не меняется. И не понимаю, почему нельзя было использовать локальные. Мне ведь они только для перестановки нужны.

Comment: можно, но почему это массивы были тогда, а не переменные?

Comment: Компилятор ругался на не совмещение типов почему-то.